# Why is LINQPAD assuming this variable is a System.Int32 and how can I change its mind?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, linqpad

I'm trying to optimize a query so I plugged it into LINQPAD but I keep getting a null reference error, can't assign null value to System.Int32.. when I comment out the FolderID one at the end there, the error no longer occurs. Why does it assume that FolderID is a System.Int32 and how can I make it an Int32? instead so it's nullable and I can run the query?

```
(from groupBundle in GroupBundles
    join userGroup in UserGroups on groupBundle.GroupID equals userGroup.GroupID
    join bundle in Bundles on groupBundle.BundleID equals bundle.BundleID
    where userGroup.UserID == 75
    orderby bundle.BundleName
    select new
    {
        BundleID = bundle.BundleID,
        BundleName = bundle.BundleName,
        BundleIcon = bundle.BundleIcon,
        UseSpecialPlayer = (bundle.UseSpecialPlayer != null && bundle.UseSpecialPlayer == true) ? true : false,
        height = bundle.PuHeight,
        width = bundle.PuWidth,
        UserID = 75,
        CompanyID = 32,
        IsFavorite = ((from f in Favorites where f.FavoriteTypeID == 1 && f.UserID == 75 && f.ActionID == bundle.BundleID select f).Count() > 0) ? true : false,

        //THIS ONE HERE
        FolderID = (from cf in CategoryFolders 
            join folder in Folders on cf.FolderID equals folder.FolderID
            where folder.CompanyID == 32 &&
            cf.CategoryID == bundle.BundleID
            select cf.FolderID).FirstOrDefault()
}).Distinct()
```

Comment: if you downvote, please comment... not sure why this is a bad question, just don't know where LINQPAD is getting the idea for this variable from since it's just a new object being created on the fly... right?

Comment: Not that I've downvoted, but you could *definitely* have simplified your example very significantly. Not only is it needlessly complex, but it's also incomplete - what is UserGroups? What is Bundles? What are the types involved? A short but *complete* example would have been a lot easier to work with.

Comment: yeah I get that, but I just wanted to include everything since I didn't know what was causing the thing to assume what FolderIDs type should be, now that they have pointed it out to me I see that you are correct, I only needed that last part, I just had no idea what it was that was determining what FolderID should be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a cast to nullable int to the expression being assigned:

```
FolderID = (int?)(from cf in CategoryFolders
```

is FolderID nullable in the database?  If not, that explains this.

Comment: I'm not sure FolderID is in the database as I am declaring a new object here... I don't know where it would be referencing this from.

Comment: ah ha, this worked and will let me continue with my task, thanks, still want to know where it is making this assumption, is it based off of what I am selecting in the sub query? because obviously FolderID is not defined anywhere..

Comment: Yes, you are selecting a new anonymous object.  But you are selecting it from: "from cf in CategoryFolders".  So what is the IQueryable source "CategoryFolders".  A Linq-to-SQL data source, yes?  So then it's defined in the database, and the type of that field determines what type Linq-to-SQL will use for the object's field in code.  Did you try the cast?  Did it work?

Comment: yep the cast worked, thanks, and yes, CategoryFolder.FolderID is non nullable, that explains it! I was thinking of it in the wrong direction

Comment: You may want to move the cast into the subquery in the select clause so it returns `int?`.  Otherwise the `FirstOrDefault()` will force it to be `0` first and always before it even gets the chance to be `null`.

Comment: The FolderID field in the database is likely a Primary Key, and is therefore NOT NULL (and is likely auto numbered too).  So L2S generates the class with an Int32 field, rather than Nullable<Int32>.  The result of the query for that field, the return type from FirstOrDefault, is Int32, because that is the type of the field you are selecting.  The anonymous object uses that information to type the field.  If the query then later tries to assign null to that field, you get the exception you did.  Casting is nothing more than a hint to the compiler here for how to type the field in the anon type.

Comment: @Jeff but if that was true then why would I be getting the null cannot be assigned to Int32 in the first place? Wouldn't it be then spitting back zero instead? When I ran it with (int?) in either location, it returned back nulls each time there was no available value (fyi)

Comment: @shogun: I'll guess that discrepency happens in the Linq to SQL conversion. FirstOrDefault is determining the anonymous type's field type, but not the runtime behavior.  That's because FirstOrDefault doesn't actually get run.  It get's translated into an equivalent SQL statement which actually returns null either way.  The cast simply fixes the compiler's generation of the anonymous type.

Comment: @shogun: If `CategoryFolder.FolderID`'s type was in fact `int?`, then the return type of `FirstOrDefault()` would also be `int?`.  You said that the resulting type is `int` suggesting it is not nullable.  The key is to make the subquery's type `IQueryable<int?>` that way `FirstOrDefault()` will actually return `(int?)null` if it is empty.  Otherwise if it were `IQueryable<int>`, you would always get `0` if it were empty.  The cast on the result only ensures that `FolderID`'s type is `int?`, but not that it will necessarily have `null` when it is supposed to.

Comment: Jeff: "you would always get 0 if it were empty", except when the LINQ provider rolls the whole thing up into a SQL query and populates the field without ever actually running the extension method FirstOrDefault.  Of course, the correct thing to do is code LINQ so that it runs consistently across providers, which your suggested modification acheives, although that is often impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that FolderId is in a database somewhere, and I would guess that it's declared as a nullable type, perhaps even a nullable Int column.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I can't post this as a comment, but does just querying this work?

```
    //THIS ONE HERE
    FolderID = (from cf in CategoryFolders 
        join folder in Folders on cf.FolderID equals folder.FolderID
        where folder.CompanyID == 32 &&
        cf.CategoryID == bundle.BundleID
        select cf.FolderID).FirstOrDefault()
```